# Draw five transparent circumcircles on the Google Map v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

I have recently started working with Google Map v2 and figured it out lot of things have been changed. Previously I was using Google Map v1 so I was using the concept of MapView.

I am trying to create `five transparent circumcircles` with the `center as my current location`. Below is the code, I was using for `Google Map v1` to draw the circle and it was working fine for me. Now I am trying to draw the same circle that I have drawn in my below code on the `Google Map v2`. I cannot use MapView here as I am using GoogleMap object here. Can anyone help me with this to draw the circle on the Google Map v2 with center as my current location

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                    (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

            // Create a LatLng object for the current location
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),  location.getLongitude());

            // Show the location on the Google Map
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            // Zoom in the Google Map
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        //   Below is the code for Google Map v1 to draw the circle on the map  

        //   if (mapOverlay == null) {
        //   mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(this, R.drawable.mark_blue);

        //   List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        //   listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
        //   }

        //   mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
        //   mapView.invalidate();
        }
}
```

A simple class that extends Overlay and draw the circle on the Google Map v1

```
class MapOverlay extends Overlay {
    private GeoPoint pointToDraw;
    int[] imageNames = new int[6];

    // This is the cached Point on the screen that will get refilled on
    // every draw
    private Point mScreenPoints;

    // This is the cached decoded bitmap that will be drawn each time
    private Bitmap mBitmap;

    // Cached Paint
    private Paint mCirclePaint;

    public MapOverlay(ProximityLocationListener gpsLocationListener,
            int currentUser) {
        imageNames[0] = currentUser;
        imageNames[1] = R.drawable.tenm;
        imageNames[2] = R.drawable.twentym;
        imageNames[3] = R.drawable.thirtym;
        imageNames[4] = R.drawable.fourtym;
        imageNames[5] = R.drawable.fiftym;

        // This only needs to be made here, once. It never needs to change.
        mCirclePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mCirclePaint.setColor(0x10000000);
        mCirclePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        // We only need to load this image once and then just keep drawing
        // it when dirtyed.
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                imageNames[0]);

        // This Point object will be changed every call to toPixels(), but
        // the instance can be recycled
        mScreenPoints = new Point();
    }

    public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
        pointToDraw = point;
    }

    public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
        return pointToDraw;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
            long when) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        mScreenPoints = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw,
                mScreenPoints);

        int totalCircle = 5;
        int radius = 40;
        int centerimagesize = 13;

        for (int i = 1; i <= totalCircle; i++) {
            canvas.drawCircle(mScreenPoints.x + 18, mScreenPoints.y + 36, i
                    * radius, mCirclePaint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    imageNames[i]), ((mScreenPoints.x) + (i * radius)),
                    (mScreenPoints.y), null);
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,
                (mScreenPoints.x - (centerimagesize / 2)),
                (mScreenPoints.y - (centerimagesize / 2)), null);
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        return true;
    }
}
```

I just need to draw the same circle that I have drawn in my above code on the Google Map v2. Is there any way, I can use the above code with GoogleMap object so that I can draw circles on the Google Map v2?

Thanks for the help.

**Updated Code:-**

I need to draw five circle-circle on the Google Maps v2 by taking the current location as the center of a circle. Meaning that each of the five circles have the same center but with different radii: the first circle will have radius of 10m, second circle radius of 20m, third circle radius of 30m, fourth circle radius of 40m, and fifth circle radius of 50m. I am using Google Maps v2.

And I need to show a marker on the center of the circle as well.

I am trying something like this to draw the circle on the Google Map v2 but it draws only one circle and not the five circum-circle

```
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
                  .center(latLng)   //set center
                  .radius(500)   //set radius in meters
                  .fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)  //default
                  .strokeColor(0x10000000)
                  .strokeWidth(5);

                  myCircle = googleMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
```

I need to draw circum-circle exactly like this-

[image]

Can anybody help me with this? I am having problem in making this circle in Google Map v2. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a circle to the map using `googleMap.addCircle(...)`

see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes)

Update:

I did exactly as I said to do and I had no problem doing what you want

[image]

here is the code, super simple super basic....

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    GoogleMap map = getMap();

    int radius = 500;

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        map.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(new LatLng(0,0)).radius(radius).fillColor(0x30000000).strokeWidth(3));
        radius += 500;
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: @tyczi, That's what I did. But I am not getting the same circle that I am getting from the above code. I need to have the same circle as I am getting from the above code. See my updated code what I am using for Google Map v2.

Comment: well there is no overlay class in v2 so this is the only way to put a circle on the map. all map objects are drawn with methods such as the circle one I posted. can you show what the differences are?

Comment: Ok. That's fine. But there should be some other way in Google Map v2 to draw the same circle that I have drawn on Google Map v1. With the above updated code, its drawing only one circle on the Map. I need to have five tranparent circumcircles.

Comment: I updated my question with the image. let me know if it is not clear to you.

Comment: OK I see what you mean now and when you add 5 circles with the same center point but different radius you get what shows in the second image? Because to me it looks like the radius is the same for all of them

Comment: Nopes. That second image with blue circle is not the way I needed. I am looking to draw circle exactly as shown in Image1 on Google Map v2. And Yes center is same for all the five circles but with different radius. And that's what I need.

Comment: well I dont know what you are doing wrong but I just did a sample app that makes 5 circles like that and had not problem. See my update

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30372/discussion-between-techgeeky-and-tyczj)